# Laravel Query Builder MySQL error on spatial functions

Tags: mysql, laravel

In Laravel 9 I am trying to execute below statement created with QueryBuilder on a MySQL 8 database

```
$distanceToNearestActivePOIInMeters = DB::table('poi')
    ->where('id', $wasActiveAtALocation[0]->venue_id)
    ->selectRaw("st_distance(location_area, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(?, ?)', 4326)) as distance", [
        $longitude, $latitude
    ])->value('distance');
```

What is odd is that I get this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens (SQL: select st_distance(location_area, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(12.4936357, 56.6599569)', 4326)) as distance from `poi` where `id` = 7 limit 1)
```

It clearly shows that it assembled the query correctly. If I run the query produced I get the correct result.

So why do I get this error about bound variables?

---

Update with learnings yet unsuccessful.

After testing i found that without any PDO it will work though it creates risk of SQL injection. Below is functioning and unsafe

```
$distanceToNearestActivePOIInMeters = DB::table('poi')
    ->where('id', $wasActiveAtALocation[0]->venue_id)
    ->selectRaw("st_distance(location_area, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(". $latitude . " " . $longitude . ")', 4326)) as distance")
    ->value('distance');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but may be this can help:

```
$distanceToNearestActivePOIInMeters = DB::table('poi')
    ->where('id', $wasActiveAtALocation[0]->venue_id)
    ->selectRaw("st_distance(location_area, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(?, ?)', 4326)) as distance")
    ->addBinding($longitude)
    ->addBinding($latitude)
    ->value('distance');
```

Comment: I tested and query becomes faulty and an error is received
´´´
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens (SQL: select st_distance(location_area, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(7, 12.4936357)', 4326)) as distance from `poi` where `id` = 56.6599569 limit 1)
´´´